# using python to project lat lon geometry to utm

Tags: python, gis, geopandas

I have a dataframe with earthquake data called eq that has columns listing latitude and longitude. using geopandas I created a point column with the following:

```
from geopandas import GeoSeries, GeoDataFrame
from shapely.geometry import Point
s = GeoSeries([Point(x,y) for x, y in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])])
eq['geometry'] = s
eq.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326', 'no_defs': True}
eq
```

Now I have a geometry column with lat lon coordinates but I want to change the projection to UTM. Can anyone help with the transformation?

Comment: Is `'epsf:4326'` a typo and should be `'epsg:4326'`? Please edit your question if so.

Comment: @help-info.de Thanks yes.

Answer (score 5):

Latitude/longitude aren't really a projection, but sort of a default "unprojection". See [this page for more details](http://www.georeference.org/doc/latitude_longitude_projection.htm), but it probably means your data uses `WGS84` or `epsg:4326`.

Let's build a dataset and, before we do any reprojection, we'll define the `crs` as `epsg:4326`

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'population' : [2, 3, 10], 'longitude': [-80.2, -80.11, -81.0], 'latitude': [11.1, 11.1345, 11.2]})
s = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(x,y) for x, y in zip(df['longitude'], df['latitude'])])

geo_df = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df[['id', 'population']], geometry=s)
# Define crs for our geodataframe:
geo_df.crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'}
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "UTM projection". From the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system) I see there are 60 different UTM projections depending on the area of the world. You can find the appropriate `epsg` code online, but I'll just give you an example with a random `epsg`code. [This is the one for zone 33N for example](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-33n/)

How do you do the reprojection? You can easily get this info from [the geopandas docs on projection](http://geopandas.org/projections.html). It's just one line:

```
geo_df = geo_df.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3395'})
```

and the geometry isn't coded as latitude/longitude anymore:

```
    id  population  geometry
0   1   2   POINT (-8927823.161620541 1235228.11420853)
1   2   3   POINT (-8917804.407449147 1239116.84994171)
2   3   10  POINT (-9016878.754255159 1246501.097746004)
```